# Copyright infringement fears for HTML video backgrounds

Tags: video, youtube, copyright-display

I'm building a website which will feature a video background. My plan was to upload a video to YouTube (unlisted) and embed this into the webpage. The footage was purchased legally through Shutterstock, however my fear is that if someone were to check the `HTML` and access the YouTube video, they could download this footage. This may breach the Shutterstock terms of "making footage easily available to third parties"

I would host the video on my own server, however I have read horror stories of bandwidth consumption with video backgrounds and the client has expressed a strong desire to keep hosting costs low.

Does anyone have any experience on the topic? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

All the best

Comment: This seems to be a chatty open-ended question and thus [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: But honestly, if you are concerned that something might breach the terms of your Shutterstock contract, then talk to Shutterstock about it.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, I have contacted support and will update this post once they reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are safe:

> Where can I use Shutterstock Footage film clips?
>
> You may use the video clips in television advertisements, educational
>   videos, web sites, multimedia presentations, broadcasting video, and
>   for many other uses. See our Licensing Terms for more details.

from https://www.shutterstock.com/video/faq/#VIDEO_FAQ_Q_WHERE_CAN_I_USE_SHUTTERSTOCK_FOOTAGE_FILM_CLIPS_